# Example for an unsatisfiable formula that can be made satisfiable by reordering quantifiers

Tags: logic, satisfiability

Please give me an example of an unsatisfiable quantified 2 CNF formula. I need it in my proof and I am unable to think of one.

I am looking for such an unsatisfiable
 quantified 2 CNF formula which gets satisfiable if the ordering of prefix is changed.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Is that so obvious for everyone ... it does not seem to be? (not saying I cannot do it).

Comment: @babou It's a [problem dump](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/751/98).

Answer (score 3):

A very simple example is

$$ \exists x \forall y (x > y) $$

where the universe is the natural numbers.

If you want just literals (i.e. universe is booleans), then another example would be

$$ \exists x \forall y ((x \land y) \lor (\neg x \land \neg y)) $$

Comment: But it doesn't get satisfiable if ordering is changed.

Comment: $$ \exists x \forall y (x > y \land x < y) $$

Comment: @Curious: Both formulae are indeed satisfiablye with $\forall \exists$. Check again!

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. But I am looking for a CNF formula.

Answer (score 1):

This

$\qquad \forall x \exists z \space (x = z)$

is a true QBF.  Whatever Boolean value $x$ is set to, $z$ can be set to match.  Translated to quantified CNF:

$\qquad \forall x \exists z \space (x \lor \lnot z) \land (\lnot x \lor z)$

Reordering the quantified variables produces

$\qquad \exists z \forall x \space (x \lor \lnot z) \land (\lnot x \lor z)$

which is a false formula because there is no value for $z$ that can be equal to both true and false at the same time.

Comment: :Thank you for the reply. So in the above example, although it is already horn, applying our method will say it is Horn renamable because the 2SAT is satisfiable. Right?

Comment: That is correct.